# How can two algorithms one with O(n^2) the other Ω(n) has about the same run time?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

How can two algorithms

- one with `O(n²)`
- the other with `Ω(n)`

have the same practical run time, when testing the algorithms with a large number?

Comment: How can someone whose height is greater than 1 meter be just as tall as someone whose height is less than 3 meters?

Comment: Big-O notation doesn't account for the coefficients. If the "faster" algorithm  has a higher coefficient, you may need very large inputs for it to overtake the slower algorithm.

Comment: This isn't even a question of coefficients; the OP is trying to compare worst-case running time to best-case running time.

Comment: @chepner, it's not about coefficient, but also not about worst/best-case distinction. O and Omega can both be applied to best/average/worst case runtime or any other function.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29972024/572670 (Don't want to single handedly close as dupe as I am the answerer, but it's basically a dupe)

Comment: @chepner NO. Omega and O are NOT worst case VS best case perormance. They are upper bound VS lower bounds of functions. I explained it some time ago in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12338937/572670). An algorithm can be worst case O(n^2) and best case O(n), and average case O(nlogn) - for example. There is no problem with that. big-O is set of *complexity functions* you can apply both analysis to big O and to big Omega.

Comment: @chepner He does however compare lower bound with upper bound

Comment: amit. Yes, I'm aware of that. In the context of the question, though, the OP is clearly talking about run-times modeled by functions with the given upper/lower bounds.

Comment: @chepner I am just commenting about the claim about comparing worst case to best case. It is not what he's doing.

Comment: He is, unless he's making the worse mistake of describing the best-case running time of an algorithm as O(n^2) or the worst-case running time as Ω(n).  "Best case O(n)" is a weak description, to the point of near uselessness, since it could leaves open the possibility that the best case is constant, logarithmic, or linear.

Answer (score 2):

`O(f(n))` is a set of functions that grow proportionally to `f(n)` or slower.

`Ω(f(n))` is a set of functions that grow proportionally to `f(n)` or faster.

There are many functions that grow at least as fast as `n`, but not faster than `n^2`. For example: `n`, `n*log n`, `n^1.5`, `n^2`.

Comment: And when you compare a specific (smaller) n the linear factors matter for both as well.